# Как отследить вызовы ядра?

Tags: c++, windows, драйвер, kernel

Есть драйвер упакованный каким то хитрым протектором. Как можно отследить какие APi ядра Windows он вызывает? Вижу только два решения: или использовать отладчик ядра (для Windows это Windbg) или извращаться с гипервизорами... Может быть есть еще варианты отследить, что происходит в ядре?
спасибо

Comment: Можно дизассемблировать и реверснуть алгоритм протектора.

Comment: это VMprotect 3 и выше... так что вариант тяжелый(

Comment: Еще вариант - https://x64dbg.com/blog/2017/06/08/kernel-driver-unpacking.html

Answer (score 0):

[Procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Логирует вызовы ядра, относящиеся к ФС, реестру, потокам, процессам.